# Can we integrate other tools (OWASP ZAP) into Nightwatch.js

Tags: nightwatch.js, zap

I am just wondering can we integrate other tools such as OWASP ZAP into Nightwatch.js to execute automated Security Testing. For e.g. starting the browser through nightwatch.js and then running/calling ZAP scripts.

Thanks & regards,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly hope so, we design ZAP so that it can be integrated with other tools as easily as possible :)

You'll need to launch ZAP (probably in daemon mode), proxy any requests you want to make through it and then control ZAP via its API.

Its difficult to be more specific without knowing more details about what you want to do :)